# how to trigger nextjs middleware on next/link

Tags: next.js, middleware

Hi i'm currently using [nextjs middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) to check authentication for every page

everything works fine when I'm navigating from the browser URL.

But when I try to navigate using `next/link`. it's skipped the middleware check.
I think this is by design on how `next/link` works because of the prefetch thing.

Is there a workaround that we can use to trigger nextjs middleware manually with `next/link` ?

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href="/admin">Admin</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not skip checking, in reality it is already done when you prefetch, If you want to check authentication/authorization please use

```
 <Link prefetch={false} />
```

(in my opinion, I see powerful in nextjs middleware and I would like to use the same as you but we used it we can't use the prefetch feature because there has a lot of bugs that I found.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your response

```js
response.headers.set(`x-middleware-cache`, `no-cache`);
```